# Linq performance when diffing two lists using inner Contains

Tags: c#, performance, linq

**EDIT 01**: I seem to have found [a solution (click for the answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50502083/1155847) that works for me. Going from and hour to merely seconds by *pre-computing* and then *applying the [`.Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx)* extension method; but leaving this open if anyone else encounters this problem **or** if anyone else finds **a better solution**.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have the following set of queries, for differend kind of objects I'm staging from a source system so I can keep it in sync and make a delta stamp myself, as the sourcesystem doesn't provide it, nor can we build or touch it.

I get all data in memory an then for example perform this query, where I look for objects that don't exist any longer in the source system, but are present in the staging database - and thus have to be marked "deleted". The bottleneck is the first part of the LINQ query - on the `.Contains()`, how can I improve it's performance - mayve with `.Except()`, with a custom comparer? 
Or should I best put them in a hashing list and them perform the compare?

The problem is though I have to have the staged objects afterwards to do some property transforms on them, this seemed the simplest solution, but unfortunately it's very slow on 20k objects

```
stagedSystemObjects.Where(stagedSystemObject => 
   !sourceSystemObjects.Select(sourceSystemObject => sourceSystemObject.Code)
        .Contains(stagedSystemObject.Code)
   )
   .Select(x =>
   {
       x.ActiveStatus = ActiveStatuses.Disabled;
       x.ChangeReason = ChangeReasons.Edited;
       return x;
   })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Race your horses!

Comment: I think this `LINQ to SQL` query create inner `select` query in `where`. You can change it `inner join` if possible and also use pagination if required

Comment: +Ankush Madanker , could you provide an example or an answer. A comment is not a fully fledged answer, I have no idea why I'd want to use pagination here. It's not Linq to SQL, it's all in memory as I said in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Yves Schelpe's answer. I made a little tweaks to make it faster.
The basic idea is to cancel the first two `ToList` and use `PLINQ`. See if this help

```
            var stagedSystemCodes = stagedSystemObjects.Select(x => x.Code);
            var sourceSystemCodes = sourceSystemObjects.Select(x => x.Code);
            var codesThatNoLongerExistInSourceSystem = stagedSystemCodes.Except(sourceSystemCodes).ToArray();

            var y = stagedSystemObjects.AsParallel()
               .Where(stagedSystemObject =>
                    codesThatNoLongerExistInSourceSystem.Contains(stagedSystemObject.Code))                  
               .Select(x =>
               {
                   x.ActiveStatus = ActiveStatuses.Disabled;
                   x.ChangeReason = ChangeReasons.Edited;
                   return x;
               }).ToArray();
```

Note that PLINQ may only work well for computational limited task with multi-core CPU. It could make things worse in other scenarios.

Comment: cool! PLINQ was on my mind indeed, but since I got this working (without PLINQ) for 200k records in under 14 seconds with a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`, I'm not going to try and risk PLINQ; as I don't know whether the servers where it'll run will support it.
PS; joe, do you know if you can easily check if PLINQ is applicable and code it int to use it when it detects that it can run here; or not. If that would be the case it would be a no brainer to build it in for those clients that could benefit from it.

Comment: PS; I think I've found the answer on whether PLINQ detects where it's running: https://stackoverflow.com/a/730339/1155847
So might be worth it indeed. Good tip, thanks.

Comment: @Yves Schelpe PLINQ is task-based and would handle things automatically by default.  By default it will use threads depending on the number of your core. In most cases the no brain way should work well.But you can still control it if you want, check `WithDegreeOfParallelism` `WithExecutionMode` and `WithMergeOptions`.But make sure you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this problem - which brought it down to mere seconds in stead of an hour for 200k objects.

It's done by *pre-computing* and then *applying the [`.Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx)* extension method

So no longer "chaining" linq queries, or doing `.Contains` inside a method... but make it "simpler" by first projecting both to a list of `string`s, so that inner calculation doesn't have to happen over and over again in the original question's example code.

Here is my solution, that for now is satisfactory. However I'm leaving this open if anyone comes up with a refined/better solution!

```
var stagedSystemCodes = stagedSystemObjects.Select(x => x.Code).ToList();
var sourceSystemCodes = sourceSystemObjects.Select(x => x.Code).ToList();
var codesThatNoLongerExistInSourceSystem = stagedSystemCodes.Except(sourceSystemCodes).ToList();

return stagedSystemObjects
   .Where(stagedSystemObject => 
        codesThatNoLongerExistInSourceSystem.Contains(stagedSystemObject.Code))
   .Select(x =>
   {
       x.ActiveStatus = ActiveStatuses.Disabled;
       x.ChangeReason = ChangeReasons.Edited;
       return x;
   })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Isn't codesThatNoLongerExistInSourceSystem  a subset of stagedSystemObjects? Why do you perform Contains again? If I understand it right , it should get codesThatNoLongerExistInSourceSystem itself.

Comment: @joe - the codes (first three lines of code) are of type `List<string>`, and merely act as a precalculation. The `codesThatNoLongerExistInSourceSystem` list is then used to get the actual `object`s with properties, so they can be worked with, and have changes applied to them - see the `.Select(x => ...)` statement for that; as the objects that have match with a code in the list `codesThatNoLongerExistInSourceSystem` should be marked as "Disabled" and "Edited". Hence why I need to do Contains there, but notice it's different than the original query. How would you do it?